# Cannot open Chrome to the right url for debugging Node.js script

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, node-inspector, node-debugger, blink-developer-tools

I run this at the command line:

```
$ node --inspect --debug-brk  test/src/dev/node/define/1.test.js
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/93a5524a-ae0a-4aa2-a985-3cd6ac6a2b9f
For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
```

**normally** this commands spits out a url that I copy and paste to the browser. At some point it also auto-opened Chrome to the right url so I could start debugging immediately which was very nice. But *now* it doesn't log the url to open, nor does it auto-open the url! Damn.

Note that the following url is not the right one to open:

```
ws://127.0.0.1:9229/93a5524a-ae0a-4aa2-a985-3cd6ac6a2b9f
```

Anybody seen this with Node.js versions 6+?

Comment: note that `node --inspect-brk` is the same as `node --inspect --debug-brk`

Answer (score 5):

I don't know why the url is no longer being printed in the console, that's a mystery, but if you look at the docs:

https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector/#chrome-devtools-55

it says:

Chrome DevTools 55+

> Option 1: Open chrome://inspect in a Chromium-based browser. Click the
>   Configure button and ensure your target host and port are listed. Then
>   select your Node.js app from the list.
>
> Option 2: Install the Chrome Extension NIM (Node Inspector Manager):
>   https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nim-node-inspector-manage/gnhhdgbaldcilmgcpfddgdbkhjohddkj

I think one of these options will work for users that face the issue in the OP. Both are working for me. Using NIM, I switched it to auto-open and it started auto-opening again for me, which is great, not sure why it was ever turned off.

Answer (score 2):

I am using the following link to see all remotely connected debuggers:
[chrome://inspect/#devices](http://chrome://inspect/#devices)

Run the debugger, open the above link in chrome and you should see there a link to connected debugger

Comment: yeah my answer already describes that, but I gave you the upvote anyway :)  see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector/#chrome-devtools-55